# Where to place "auch"

Tags: sentence-structure

Which one is correct?

> ich wohne auch in Berlin.

or

> ich wohne in Berlin auch.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach So auch always comes after the verb?? For example Herr Smith ist auch mein Arbeitgeber. Ich komme auch aus deutschland.

Comment: @c.p. Your last example sounds very unnatural to me. I would say "Ich verbringe das Wochenende in Potsdam, jedoch wohne ich auch in Berlin."

Comment: Non of both. In German all sentences have to begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Hubert: could be just part of a sentence. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Auch** is placed the same way as **nicht**. You put it in front of the item you want to insist on.

> Ich wohne auch in Berlin. — Ich wohne nicht in Berlin.
>
> Auch ich wohne in Berlin. — Nicht ich wohne in Berlin.

Exception: you cannot put it in front of the verb in second position. It goes to the end of the clause then. Same as with *nicht*.

> Das glaube ich auch. — Das glaube ich nicht.

It gets interesting if you have both *nicht* and *auch* in front of an item.

> Ich wohne auch nicht in Berlin.
>
> Ich wohne nicht auch in Berlin.

These mean a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

"Ich wohne auch in Berlin" is correcht, the other one is wrong.

> @jonathan.scholbach So auch always comes after the verb?? For example Herr Smith ist auch mein Arbeitgeber. Ich komme auch aus deutschland.

yes, All your examples, that you typed in your comment, are correct, the "auch" always is after the verb. Even if this makes some things ambiguous. "Herr Smith ist auch mein Arbeitgeber" does not make clear, if the "auch" is meant for "Herr Smith" or for "Arbeitgeber". it could mean Smith too is a bos, so I have several bosses and he is one of them. or it could mean Smith is a boss too, so he is my brother, by friend and also by boss. The english grammar is more clear than the german grammar in this point.

Comment: That is not the full story. _Herr Schmidt ist auch mein Arbeitgeber_ could be translated to __Mr. Schmidt is also my employer__ or to __Mr. Schmidt is my employer, too.__. The ambiguity in the german sentence is the same as in the english translations.

Comment: When answering, please assume that comments are not permanent.

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: "Ich wohne in Berlin auch" is actually a valid sentence but unusual because one would only say that only if s/he wants to put a strong emphasis on "auch". Less unusual is "In Berlin wohne ich auch" which shows that "auch" *can* be last. "Auch wohne ich in Berlin" is valid too, but it means something different: That one wants to add the fact that s/he is living in Berlin to what was said previously. So you can place "auch" almost anywhere (except position 2 where the verb belongs) but it depends on what exactly you want to say.

Comment: Citation: "... the 'auch' always is after the verb." This is not correct. See, for example, the valid sentences "Auch Herr Smith ist mein Arbeitgeber" and "Herr Smith glaubt das auch nicht".